# How can I create a shortcut to dual boot between ChromeOS and Ubuntu easily?

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

It took my quite a while to find this information, and unlike most topics it was not on StackOverflow (or at least I couldn't find it).

---

It used to be I used the `qemacs` editor on chromeos (CR48) to change the `.profile` file. I couldn't find the updated one for the newer Samsung chromebooks, so

**question:**
*How can I create the shortcut to dual boot between ChromeOS and Ubuntu easily?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit goes to:** [cr-48.wikispace.com/Dual+Boot+shortcuts](http://cr-48.wikispaces.com/Dual+Boot+Shortcuts)

---

After completing these steps you will be able to switch to Ubuntu from Chrome OS by simply entering the command ubuntu in the terminal.

You will be able to switch to Chrome OS from Ubuntu by entering the command chromeos in the terminal.

Install Ubuntu using the instructions here

Boot into Ubuntu and navigate to the Home folder

Press ctrl + h

Double-click the file .bashrc

Scroll to the bottom of the file and add this command: alias chromeos='sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 0 /dev/sda;sudo reboot'

Save the file and close it

Open a terminal by selecting Applications > Accessories > Terminal and type chromeos

After entering your password (the default password is 'user'), the computer should reboot into Chrome OS

Log in to Chrome OS and press ctrl + alt + → (→ is the forward arrow where the F2 key would normally be)

Type chronos and press enter

Type sudo vim .profile and press enter (to see a complete list of vim editor commands go 
here)

Press the letter a to begin 'insert mode'

Type alias ubuntu='sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda;sudo reboot'

Press esc to return to 'command mode'

Press shift + z then shift + z again to save the file and return to the terminal

Type exit and press enter

Type chronos to log in again and press enter

Type ubuntu and press enter

The computer should reboot into Ubuntu